# Eclipse (Photon) couldn't find my maven dependency jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import a library from my maven repo. But I got the error saying `"The import org cannot be resolved"`, screenshot below:

[image]

However, we can see the jar under the Maven Dependencies from the Package explorer:

[image]

Also, my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test1</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>10</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>gregorian-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What did I miss here? What else do I need to `import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils` ? Thanks!

Note: I am on Mac

Comment: Did you try refreshing the Maven project?

Comment: Yes, refreshed many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a `module-info.java`.
In this case, you need to add `requires org.apache.commons.lang3;` to it (this is the automatic module name from the `MANIFEST.MF` inside `commons-lang3-3.8.jar`).

Also, having MainTest1 in the default package is not allowed in a named module, so you have to move it into a package.

Alternatively, you can remove the `module-info.java` and things should mostly work like before Java 9

Comment: Thank you! Works for Java 10 by removing the module-info.java